# Pulling non-blank date value for where ID matches and there exist both blank and non-blank values for same ID

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a report that has rows where a UserID shows up multiple times.

I am needing to pull the start date (non-blank field) for any row where the UserID matches the reference UserID (matching the userID is easy) only for rows where an additional column (field) value includes “classroom workshop”.

Example source worksheet ID field is A column where the UserID is occurs four times. Only one of the four occurrences of the same ID has a date value in the Training Start Date field. The MATCH is being done between the source worksheet and target worksheet.

This is the current function written: It does not ignore blanks, if it comes across a blank value it will report 1/0/1900 instead of searching for the first non-blank field with matching userID.

```
=INDEX(SourceWS!$A$8:$P$615,MATCH(A5,SourceWS!$A$8:$A$615,0),12)
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.